# How can I efficiently deliver large number of assets (images)?

Tags: php, http, web-applications, nginx, varnish

I have a single web page that will be responsible for delivery over 500 images to the browser.  The sizes vary between 50kb and 80kb.

The server being used is nginx and there is a varnish proxy also being used.

Now, how can I make this process the most efficient it can possibly be?

I have only two thoughts and so would like some imput from experienced people here.

My only thoughts are:

1. Set up multiple subdomains and serve batches from these. I believe that the best number of subdomains to use would be 12.
2. Use ajax to load batches to the browser only when needed as the user scrolls down.

I think option 2 here doesn't really solve the problem; just gets around it.  So I would like to focus on actually making the process the most efficient and the fastest it can possibly be.

Comment: I think option 2 would be best. Why waste both your and your users bandwidth on something that is never seen? You could combine it with option nr. 1 ofcourse.

Answer (score 1):

You're loading 1 page with 500*50kb ~ 25MB of data, that's a completely insane pagesize!

No matter what you do that's always gonna feel slow compared to an [average pagesisze of around 1 MB currently](http://httparchive.org/trends.php#bytesTotal&reqTotal). Loading most of it dynamically via AJAX when needed makes way more sense. Alternatively you could split it into multiple plages.

If you're really set on the one giant non-dynamic page then:

- make sure you have cache headers set to allow caching (won't hep with first load)
- the main problem (apart from the overall size) is that you have an awfull lot of resources you're requesting. there's 3 ways to limit the consequences of that:

  - use sharding (i.e. different subdomains). This works because browses will open only up to 4 connections per host, so by using multiple domains you can request/load more resources in parallel.
  - put your images in a sprite (i.e. one big image, and use css to display the bit you want)
  - set up your server to use google's SPDY. This pretty much eliminates the problem with 
    lots of resources. Downside is that it's still experimental (i.e. you'll need to 
    recompile nginx with the patches) and is not supported by all browers yet